# Overwriting files properly

Tags: php

I am trying to manage caching on heavily used webpage written in PHP. I have marked some cacheable sections of PHP code, which I want to execute only pre-cache when administrator make changes in CMS. For this, I use this method:

I have file (for example "index-source.php") with some marked ares of PHP code, which are interpretable alone. When admin change some settings, these marked parts are executed and replaced with result (for example MySQL queries which reads menu items from DB are replaced with generated HTML menu). Resulted file is saved as new "index.php", which still have some PHP code, which can't be optimized by caching.

**Now to my problem**
If we assume, that this server is heavilly load, which means there is for example 100 requests per second, which in PHP requires file index.php. If I will use file_put_contents() to overwrite this index.php with new pre-cached version, is there any risk, that some requests will be interrupted, because of locked/not fully overwritten file? Basically I want to somehow update my PHP file and assure that PHP will include complete old or complete new version of that file or wait few milliseconds until file is overwritten. I **dont't** want PHP to fail require or load partially overwritten file.

Is that possible? Thanks

Comment: 100 requests per second is not heavily loaded

Comment: That was only example. There can be situations when 100 req/s can be on one article out of thousands others. It was not meant as representative sample of whole website.

Answer (score 0):

`file_put_contents` is not what you want.

Have a look at this project, and dive into the source to get a feel for what challenges you may have to face as well as the solution chosen.

https://github.com/PHPSocialNetwork/phpfastcache

Comment: Thanks, I will try to look into. I just want this option as very simple and universal caching solution for my CMS, which does not need any advanced settings, tweaks, specific php modules or configuration.

Comment: Well I examinated the source code for "files" driver of phpfastcache and it doesn't solve this problem. So this problem either not exists and it is safe, or it has this problem also. It simply overwrites cache file with fopen/fwrite/fclose and has not any prevention of reading incompleted files.

Comment: Yes, overwriting the cache is correct.  Overwriting the source file isn't.  Anyway, I thought it may help.

Comment: I believe it is the same thing. Because it uses cached file, if file exists, but it can also read in incompletely updated. So results are the same - corrupted output.